# Prepend to subversion checkin template

Tags: svn

Command line subversion has the convenient feature of bringing up a checkin "template" of sorts (in the editor specified with the environment variable SVN_EDITOR) upon executing `svn ci` :

```
(blank line)
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

M   src/myfile.c
A   src/otherfile.c
```

I love this feature because it gives a quick summary of changes to be committed without having to run `svn status` and filter through `?` results.

What I'd like to do is grep some stuff from the previous commit's log message and prepend it to the message, like so:

```
Some stuff I grepped from the previous log message.
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

M   src/myfile.c
A   src/otherfile.c
```

I've considered creating a script that creates this log message manually by parsing the output of `svn status` and then removes it before the actual commit is made, but that seems like it might be overly complex or screw up some other feature of the checkin tool.  Is there a better / simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways you could do this. `svn ci` takes a commit message as an argument with the `-m` flag so you could prepare your message and pass it as a string. Something like this:

```
$ svn ci -m "$(svn log | grep Magic\ Text)"
```

`checkin` also takes a filename with `-F`, so you could also do something like this:

```
$ svn log | grep Magic\ Text > temp.log
$ svn ci -F temp.log
$ rm temp.log
```

Or, if you don't want to deal with having a temporary file, passing just `-` as the argument to `-F` makes `checkin` read from `stdin`:

```
$ svn log | grep Magic\ Text | svn ci -F -
```

**--- EDIT ---**

It looks like this isn't exactly what you wanted. If you wanted a way to basically "hook" into the commit and edit the commit message template, this should work for you. When `svn commit` is run, it creates a file called `svn-commit.tmp` in the current directory. We can override the `$SVN_EDITOR` environment variable to use a custom script that edits the `svn-commit.tmp` file and then lets us edit it more. Here's what worked for me.

Create a file somewhere (maybe in $HOME/bin or something) that'll be your new `$SVN_EDITOR`. Place this inside of it:

```
#!/bin/bash

svn log | grep Whatever > svn-commit2.tmp
cat svn-commit.tmp >> svn-commit2.tmp
mv svn-commit2.tmp svn-commit.tmp
vi svn-commit.tmp
```

Now in your shell, or in your `~/.bashrc` put the following line:

```
export SVN_EDITOR="$HOME/bin/your_editor.sh"
```

Make sure to source your `bashrc` if you put it in there.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now when you do a commit, it should have some extra lines in there. This is sort of a hacky solution, but it works.